# plotting geometry directely from postgis using geopandas and python on ubuntu

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql-9.4

i'm trying to plot a geometry from postgis using geopandas and python, but i'm not getting anything (no error, no result).
here's the code i'm using, am I missing anything ?

```
import psycopg2
import geopandas as gpd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='strokes' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='admin'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
ba = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("SELECT ST_AsText(geom) AS wkt, fid_limite, nombassin FROM bassin", conn, geom_col ='geometry', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, coerce_float=True)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    ba.head
    ba.plot(column='nombassin', categorical=True, legend=True, figsize=(14,6));
    plt.show()
```